# передать большое число в функцию java

Tags: java, calendar, преобразование, simpledateformat

как передать длинное значение toStartMethods.increaseThisDay(23985293465927364592364592364592374569629476239457254);

в эту функцию (с огромным числом не работает)

**

```
public void increaseThisDay(long seconds) {
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(SECOND, (int) seconds);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat newData = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("If we add our seconds in today's date we will have  " + newData.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

**

Comment: BigInteger вам в помощь

Comment: Почитайте про ограничения для long, int и пр...

Comment: Это число не содержит даты и времени

Comment: Но зачем? Вселенная погибнет от тепловой смерти намного раньше получающейся даты.

Comment: @Yaant но Александр уже будет очень далеко от нашей вселенной...

Comment: кому-то значит это надо

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Java не поддерживает такого рода целочисленный литерал или литерал типа BigInteger

```
public static void increaseThisDay(BigInteger seconds) {
    ....
}

increaseThisDay(new BigInteger("23985293465927364592364592364592374569629476239457254"));
```

Comment: BigInteger не подходит. нужно каким-то образом через Char

Answer (score 0):

если в вызове функции использовать число интового значения - все работает хорошо, лонг уже не проходит. Советуют через преобразование Char c созданием в main отдельной функции - но что прописывать в этой функции и самое главное как передать значение в функцию преобразующую дату - тут уже нужен совет профессионала

**

```
public void increaseThisDay(long seconds) {
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(SECOND, (int) seconds);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat newData = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("If we add our seconds in today's date we will have  " + newData.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

**